# Definitive answer to what playersToInvite is for

Tags: objective-c, ios, gamekit, game-center

The Game Center documentation indicates that the

> `playersToInvite` parameter is non-nil
>   when your application is launched
>   directly from the Game Center
>   application to host a match.

A few people have asked how this works exactly, i.e. there doesn't appear to be a way to select a friend from the Game Center application and invite them to play *from* Game Center; it only works when you invite in-game. Is this documentation dated or is there a secret way to start a game-specific match from Game Center? I'd like to test my `inviteHandler` but I've been unable to determine how this parameter is passed to the application.

```
[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite)
{
    // clean up games in progress here
    if (acceptedInvite)
    {
        NSLog(@"acceptedInvite %@", acceptedInvite);
        // The acceptedInvite parameter is non-nil when the application receives an 
        // invitation directly from another player.
        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
        [self disableHomeUI];
        [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
    }
    else if (playersToInvite)
    {
        NSLog(@"playersToInvite %@", playersToInvite);
        // playersToInvite parameter is non-nil when your application is launched 
        // directly from the Game Center application to host a match
        [self disableHomeUI];
        [self doPresentMatchMakerUIWithPlayersToInvite:playersToInvite];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After launching my application Cee-lo into production, the `playersToInvite` code became active. This seems to be because the Sandbox version of the Game Center app itself does not allow you to start a game with a player from there, but the production version does. Not a very good test environment if you ask me!

Answer (score 1):

I think the docs do not reflect the current state of affairs. As far as I can tell, the Game Center App does not even offer an interface for inviting friends to play, currently.

Also, check the developer forums (apparently you have ;) ). Someone from Cupertino seems to think it is not possible. So...

Answer (score 1):

There *is* now a way to use the Game Center app to invite a Game Center friend. It ONLY works if your game calls registerListener: on the localPlayer GKPlayer:

Game Center App
-> games tab
-> your game
-> Players section
-> select a player
-> "Play a Game"

This will send a push notification invite to the other player. Game does *not* have to be running on either device. As of iOS7.

This flow also works:
Game Center App
-> friends tab
-> tap a friend
-> tap a game in common (your game)
-> tap the "..." in the top right corner
-> tap "Play"

Comment: So, will the invitee receive the invite notification after I tapped "Play" in the Game Center app?  Or my app will need to send out invitation directly?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but i think it is just the "simulator" that can not invite particular friends to play.

I have been able to use 2 or more iPhones running in the sandbox to invite particular friends to play, and it has worked wonderfully for debugging the invite handler piece of code.

### As another poster mentioned, there does not appear to be at this time a way of inviting particular friends to play a particular game from Game Center.

Happy gaming!