# iOS 7: How to setup invitation handler for Game Center matchmaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

What is the proper way to handle invitations from other players in iOS 7?

After my view did load on my root View Controller, I'm calling a game center authentication method, after that I'm setup a invitation handler like so:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] registerListener:self];
```

My view controller adopt `GKLocalPlayerListener` and `GKInviteEventListener` protocols, by the way, what is the best place to register a listener AppDelegate? Maybe or maybe my custom Game Center singleton?

I add a method described in `GKInviteEventListener`

```
-(void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didAcceptInvite:(GKInvite *)invite
{
    NSLog(@"Invite accepted!");
    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:invite];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

But, game center matchmaker class have such topic: Receiving Invitations From Other Players and method `– matchForInvite:completionHandler:`
I don't understand how to use it.

So, what I must use and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're doing things correctly. I did things the same way, and it works for me. -`matchForInvite:completionHandler` is deprecated in iOS 7, so I don't do anything with it.

First I set the authentication handler. This is called when my app loads for the first time, you can set it anywhere you like, but it is best to set the handler as soon as possible.

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

    //Block is called each time GameKit automatically authenticates
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
    {
        [self setLastError:error];
        if (viewController)
        {
            self.authenticationViewController = viewController;
            [self disableGameCenter];
        }
        else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            [self authenticatedPlayer:blockLocalPlayer];
        }
        else
        {
            [self disableGameCenter];
        }
    };
}
```

If authentication is successful, then I call this method:

```
-(void)authenticatedPlayer:(GKLocalPlayer*)localPlayer
{
    self.isAuthenticated = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]registerListener:self];
}
```

Then I implemented the two listener methods:

```
(void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didAcceptInvite:(GKInvite *)invite
{
       //.... insert some cleanup code here to manage view controllers etc before presenting the matchmakerviewcontroller.
        [self presentMatchmakerViewControllerWithInvite:invite];
}


-(void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didRequestMatchWithPlayers:(NSArray *)playerIDsToInvite
{
    //......insert some cleanup code for managing view controllers 
    GKMatchRequest *match = [[GKMatchRequest alloc]init];
    match.playersToInvite = playerIDsToInvite;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc]initWithMatchRequest:match];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = root.viewControllers[0];
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController]presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help me to understand what's going on.

Comment: To be honest, you sound like you're doing exactly what I'm doing, and it seems you're doing things correctly. I wouldn't even bother reading my code. You should be focusing on the general flow of your app. Your game center stuff is probably correct.

Comment: thanks I hope so, I want ask you one more thing, do you made a singleton class that is responsible for all GC stuff or you made this another way?

Comment: All of my GC methods which have nothing to do with anything else are in a singleton class. But I haven't finished my game, so things could change. You should focus on YOUR app, and see what makes sense for what you are doing.

Comment: Hey John, I'm a bit confused and I'm hoping you can clear this up for me. Why would you want to display the matchmaker viewcontroller in [player:didAcceptInvite:]? When an invite is accepted wouldn't you want to open the new game?

Comment: The GKInvite doesn't have a match object as a match hasn't been created yet.I create a GKMatchmakerViewController using: [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc]initWithInvite:invite], and assign the delegate, so once the match has been created (after the minimum number of players accept the invite), the same methods I use to start the game (as if I created a match request myself) are called by the controller. Also you get to see the other players who may be in the game. I'm not aware of any other way to get a match object, but from reading the docs and other tutorials I decided to go this way.

Comment: Is player:didAcceptInvite: ever called? What sequence of steps triggers it? It seems that it is never called in my app.

Comment: Yes it gets called. When the recipient of the invite accepts the invite, the inviter gets the method called. I can't comment on your app because I don't know what your code looks like, but if you follow the game center programming guide it should be straight forward how invitations should flow.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more precise wrt the documentation? I've read it through and the method is never mentioned in the GC programming guide. As for my app, I have a dummy implementation of the method in the GKPlayerListener delegate that just NSLogs something to the console, but it is never called (other methods are called, instead, like player:receivedTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:, so pointers are set). I expected that when another player accepts the invitation from the GC app, this method would be called at the local player's side, but it isn't. So I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: My experience is with "Real time" multiplayer gaming, so I don't know if it is different for Turn based gaming. I worked on this a while back so I really don't remember which part of the guide I was reading - But I did just read the guide, and play around with it, so I imagine if you created a simple app for the sole purpose of just testing GC, you should be able to figure out the API.

Comment: IOS8: player:didRequestMatchWithPlayers: is deprecated. you should call player:didRequestMatchWithRecipients: instead.