# GameCenter didAcceptInvite not called

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm developing a turn-based game with iOS GameCenter. I use the default `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` for matchmaking and invites. However after sending and accepting an invite, the `player:didAcceptInvite:` method is not called. I expected that this method will be called after the other player has accepted the invite from the local player.

So my questions are:

1) How do you trigger `player:didAcceptInvite:`?

2) How do you inform the local player if the invite was declined?

I am targeting iOS 7+ and use two real devices for testing.

The following method will be called after the local player is authenticated:

```
-(void)onPlayerAuthenticationChanged
{
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated)
    {
        if (!self.isLocalPlayerAuthenticated)
        {
            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] registerListener:self];
            self.isLocalPlayerAuthenticated = YES;
        }
    }
    //…
}
```

The GC singleton conforms to the `GKLocalPlayerListener` protocol, which includes `GKInviteEventListener` and therefore `player:didAcceptInvite:`. My implementation looks roughly like the suggested solution in [iOS 7: How to setup invitation handler for Game Center matchmaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166617/ios-7-how-to-setup-invitation-handler-for-game-center-matchmaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation doesn't state this, I've learned through experimentation that `didAcceptInvite` only fires for real time matches. It does not fire for turn-based matches. It's unclear if this is by design (and the documentation is wrong) or it's broken. I have an open bug with Apple on this.

However, as an alternative, `receivedTurnEventForMatch` does fire, though, when the invited player starts playing. If there's something you need to do when the other player accepts the invite, try putting it in `receivedTurnEventForMatch`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The GC documentation is often confusing or even outdated.